# Heap-sort 'Heapify' iterative procedure

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I was checking the iterative approach for the max-heapify algorithm and the following is what is given in CLRS solutions.

```
while i < A.heap-size do
l =LEFT(i)
r =LEFT(i)
largest = i
if l ≤ A.heap-size and A[l] > A[i] then
largest = l
end if
if r ≤ A.heap-size and A[r] > A[i] then
largest = r
end if
if largest not equal i then
exchange A[i] and A[largest]
i = largest
else return A
end if
end while
return A
```

My question is why the loop condition is given as `i < A.heap-size`? Since the left and right should be within the heap size, which would mean that the parent must be `i <= A.heap-size/2`, why can't we check the condition as such `i<=A.heap-size/2`?

Comment: It's valid to check that instead, but it's clearer as written (and probably the optimization does not speed things up in any significant way). By the way, there's a typo in your algorithm -- `if l ≤ A.heap-size and A[r] > A[i] then` should be `if r ≤ A.heap-size and A[r] > A[i] then`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are correct , it is just sufficient to check till heap-size/2. After that we don't even have children for those nodes.